# Mail Merge comparison between fields

Tags: microsoft-word, csv, mail-merge

I have a meeting merge document which is populated from a CSV file with data entered online from a facilitator. I am unable to work out how to do multiple conditions, there are a maximum of 10 clients attending each meeting. 
{Client1_attended} = y/n {client1_state}, {Client2_attended} = y/n {client2_state}....etc
If attendees are in the same state “meeting held at…..” if attendees are not in the same state “meeting held via teleconference” - any suggestions would be welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use IF fields to insert conditional pieces of text. You can read more about IF fields in this great FAQ: http://word.mvps.org/faqs/mailmerge/mmergeiffields.htm